# Decrypt encrypted value using DPAPI

Tags: encryption, connection-string, dpapi

I have encrypted value and I tried to decrypt it using `asp_regiis.exe`.

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings 
    configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl....fK39sbTH</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I run this command:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\Test"
```

I have this error:

> Decrypting configuration section...
>
> Failed to decrypt using provider 'DataProtectionConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider:
>
> ```
> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
> Failed!
> ```

What seems wrong with this? I need to find the decrypted value.
Please advise.

Comment: how did you encrypt data ? because encryption could be at the computer level or at the user level

Comment: Actually I don't know how was the data was encrypted. It was encrypted few years ago by the developer and we need to change it now since we change our database.

Comment: I just want to know how can I know the value of this encrypted data and how can I input/place the new encrypted value for our new database.

Comment: if it was encripted as the computer level, you can use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194223/dpapi-password-encryption-in-c-sharp-and-saving-into-database-then-decrypting-it/34196810#34196810. Otherwise if the data has been encrypted at the user level, you need to decrypt the data using the same user account

Comment: if you dont need to decrypt the data, you can see this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I will try your first suggestion above. On the next comment, I already tried to encrypt the new database and the replaced the connString value with the new encrypted data. But I encountered this error when accessing the site.

Comment: Here is the error when I tried to access the site... Error Id :421a46fd-2690-4480-a6cb-0794f07f95e3 Error Type: five - ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Error Message :An unhandled exception has occurred.

Comment: Error InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The web server has been unable to contact the Federation Server. at System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.WSPersistentState.GetPersistentInfo(TrustedRealm& trustedRealm, String& fsAccountName) at System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.WebSsoAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateWithWSFederationPassive() at System.Web.Security.SingleSignOn.WebSsoAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object o, EventArgs args) - End of inner exception stack trace

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for that..

Comment: The new encrypted value was place on this section:                 <appSettings>
     <add key="CommandTimeOut" value="31" />
     <add key="ApplicationName" value="Arch" />
     <add key="EnableDatabaseAuditing" value="False" />
     <add key="LastTransactionIDParameterName" value="LastTransactionID" />
     <add key="CurrentDateTimeDB" value="ArchRefDataDB" />
     <add key="connString" value="AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAKGHR.........."

Comment: The connstring value was called in the code behind through:                        Dim dtaRetriever As DataRetriever = New DataRetriever()
connString = dtaRetriever.GetAppSettingKey("connString")

Comment: Anyone who can help me on this?