# Converting string into REG_BINARY

Tags: vb.net, binary, type-conversion, registry

I am making an app in visualstudios's VB to autoinstall the printer in windows. Problem is, that the printer needs a login and pass. I found registry entry, where this is stored, but the password is stored in `REG_BINARY` format.

Here is how it looks after manually writing the password into printer settings - see UserPass:
[image]

Please could you tell me how to convert password (in string) into the reg_binary (see attachement - red square)?

The password in this case was `09882` and it has been stored as `98 09 e9 4c c3 24 26 35 14 6f 83 67 8c ec c4 90`. Is there any function in VB to convert `09882` into this `REG_BINARY` format please?

Comment: It looks like [DPAPI password encryption in C# and saving into database.Then Decrypting it using a key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194223/1115360) could have the information you need.

Comment: Thank you! This looks very useful, unfortunately it's in C#. I actually dont know C# language. VB.net only :-(

Comment: The methods are the same; please see [ProtectedData Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and choose "VB" in the dropdown to the left of "Bookmark" in the section at the top-right of the page to see what you'd need in VB.

Answer (score 2):

`REG_BINARY` means that it is binary data and binary data in .NET is represent by a `Byte` array. The values you see in RegEdit are the hexadecimal values of the individual bytes, which is a common representation because every byte can be represented by two digits. You need to convert your `String` to a `Byte` array and then save it to the Registry like any other data.

How you do that depends on what the application expects. Maybe it is simply converting the text to `Bytes` based on a specific encoding, e.g. `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes`. Maybe it's a hash. You might need to research and/or experiment to find out exactly what's expected.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, this helps me at least where to start. Thank you!

Comment: For the record, I tested and determined that that sequence of bytes does not represent the ASCII, UTF8 or Unicode encoding of that password or the SHA1 or MD5 hash of any of those.

Comment: That's what I was affraid of. Thank you for your investigation! Really helped me.